# Concrete Examples of Complex Term Analysis Using Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, analytic-philosophy

In all of my textbooks, there are no concrete case studies of how one can use predicate logic to analyze specific characteristics of complex terms. I am therefore looking for an exemplar for the analysis of an ambiguous and vague complex term. Does anyone know of any that they would recommend? Preferably something peer reviewed.

Comment: What do you mean by "specific characteristics of complex terms"? What kinds of characteristics? What terms are you talking about? What is a complex term?

Comment: At complex term is one that is related to other terms but does not imply the conjunction of their properties. For example, fast money. The term has some relation to fast and money but it does not literally mean "a medium of exchange moving at high-speed." In the ordinary sense, fast is ambiguous (it has multiple meanings as evidenced by a quick review of a dictionary). And, the complex term fast money seems to lack a defined field of application. I am trying to find an example of the process by which one can analyze such complex terms from the perspective of vagueness and ambiguity.

Comment: In *first order* (or *predicate*) logic, a *term* is a "name" for an object; terms can be "simple" like an individual *contstant* (e.g.0 and 1) or "complex", like S(S(S(0)))+1 wich denotes the number "four". Your example : "fast money" is more like a "predicate"; in f-o logic, we have again "simple" preidcates, denoted by *predicate letters* (e.g. P, Q, ...) and "complex" ones, obtained by "boolean" composition of simple ones. Every f-o formula A(x) with one free variable can express a (unary) preidcate, i.e. the predicate which "identify" the set of objects satisfying the formula.